# My heart button state in TableViewCell is saved when the cell gets reused

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm filling the table view using xib. Each cell has a button with a heart image which can be filled or not. When button is selected it adds the row where the button is to a favourite view. So far it's working. The problem is that when I scroll the table view the cell that gets reused is shown up with a filled heart instead of an empty one.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
       let cellIdentifier = "cell"
       let cell = productTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier ,for :indexPath)
           as! ProductsTableViewCell
       let model = productArray[indexPath.row]
       cell.favouriteButton.tag = indexPath.row
       cell.configureCell(model)

       return cell
   }else {
       let cellIdentifier = "cell2"
       let cell = productTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Product2TableViewCell
       let model = productArray[indexPath.row]
       cell.favouriteButton.tag = indexPath.row

       if favouriteProductsArray.count != 0 {
           for fave in favouriteProductsArray {
               if fave.product_id == model.id{
                   cell.favouriteButton.isSelected = true
               }
           }
       }else{
           cell.favouriteButton.isSelected = false
       cell.setupCell(model)
       return cell
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where's your code that determines whether the heart should be filled or not?

Comment: I've used a library for the heart called FaveButton witch makes the heart filled when .isSelected is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the following code:

```
if favouriteProductsArray.count != 0 {
    for fave in favouriteProductsArray {
        if fave.product_id == model.id{
            cell.favouriteButton.isSelected = true
        }
    }
}else{
    cell.favouriteButton.isSelected = false
}
```

In the first `if` statement, you have no logic to set `isSelected` to `false`. I would redo that code as follows:

```
var selected = false
if favouriteProductsArray.count != 0 {
    for fave in favouriteProductsArray {
        if fave.product_id == model.id {
            selected = true
            break
        }
    }
}
cell.favouriteButton.isSelected = selected
```

This ensures `isSelected` is set to `false` unless you find a matching id.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. This solved my problem and saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. What I did was have an array to track the .isSelected value, and after dequeuereusablecell set the isSelected based on the values in the array. This could just be an if statement.

So that would be an array of n elements, where n is the number of food items you are loading. Each element would be true or false, which is the respective value for isSelected, which is set after dequeuereusablecell.

Answer (score 0):

While you properly set up the favorite button in the else part, you fail to do so when the if-condition is true. Do it there, too. Or better yet, extract the code to do it outside of the if statement.